# Taking rows from a dataframe and turning them into columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1=
    testID  Time  containsMedia  overallScore  Difficulty
    a1      134      0            0.70           Easy
    a2      345      0            0.22           Hard
    a3      355      0               1           Easy
    a4      444      1               0           Hard
    a5      356      1            0.89           Easy
```

And

```
df2=
        TypeOfTest        testID    Parameter   partialScore
        Prep              a1        3            0.70
        Exam              a1        5            0.80
        Final             a1        6            0.60
        Prep              a2        3            0.01
        Final             a2        2            0.90
        Prep              a3        1            0.79
        Exam              a3        5            0.11
        None              a4        5               1
        Exam              a5        3            0.89
```

I want:

```
testID  Time  containsMedia  overallScore  Difficulty   Prep   Exam  Final  None
a1      134      0            0.70           Easy       0.70   0.80  0.60
a2      345      0            0.22           Hard       0.01         0.90
a3      355      0               1           Easy       0.79   0.11
a4      444      1               0           Hard                              1
a5      356      1            0.89           Easy              0.89
```

Probably with NaNs in the blank spaces.
I tried:

```
result_test = pd.concat([df1, df2 , df2, df2, df2] axis=1)
```

and it just glues them together. How is it possible to do this? What do I do with the None/NaNs?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) + [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join) with an optional [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to get columns in correct order:

```
result_df = df1.join(
    df2.pivot(index='testID', columns='TypeOfTest', values='partialScore')
        .reindex(columns=['Prep', 'Exam', 'Final', 'None']),
    on='testID'
)
```

*Without `reindex` `df2` columns will be in alphabetical order.

`result_df`:

```
  testID  Time  containsMedia  overallScore Difficulty  Prep  Exam  Final  None
0     a1   134              0          0.70       Easy  0.70  0.80    0.6   NaN
1     a2   345              0          0.22       Hard  0.01   NaN    0.9   NaN
2     a3   355              0          1.00       Easy  0.79  0.11    NaN   NaN
3     a4   444              1          0.00       Hard   NaN   NaN    NaN   1.0
4     a5   356              1          0.89       Easy   NaN  0.89    NaN   NaN
```

---

[`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) can be used to replace `NaN` with empty strings:

```
result_df = df1.join(
    df2.pivot(index='testID', columns='TypeOfTest', values='partialScore')
        .reindex(columns=['Prep', 'Exam', 'Final', 'None'])
        .fillna(''),
    on='testID'
)
```

`result_df`:

```
  testID  Time  containsMedia  overallScore Difficulty  Prep  Exam Final None
0     a1   134              0          0.70       Easy   0.7   0.8   0.6     
1     a2   345              0          0.22       Hard  0.01         0.9     
2     a3   355              0          1.00       Easy  0.79  0.11           
3     a4   444              1          0.00       Hard                    1.0
4     a5   356              1          0.89       Easy        0.89
```